# duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 - ios

Tags: ios, sdk

I have a problem with my ios app. As soon as i integrate a admob adapter, i run into some issues. What can i do?

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDataScanner.data in:
>           /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDataScanner.o
>           /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CDataScanner.o)
>
> ```
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.nullObject in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.strictEscapeCodes in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _kJSONScannerErrorDomain in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.allowedEncoding in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CJSONScanner.options in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONScanner in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONScanner in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONScanner.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONScanner.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CJSONSerialization in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONSerialization.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONSerialization.o)
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONSerialization in:
>     /Users/Sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TrackQuiz-fyuyditzrtsdmgbefbdoggekhfeg/Build/Intermediates/TrackQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/TrackQuiz.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CJSONSerialization.o
>     /Users/Sven/Documents/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS7/AdMobMeditation/MobFox/AdMobAdapter/libAdapterSDKMobFox.a(CJSONSerialization.o)
> ld: 30 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Any help would be great! Sorry, but i don´t know, where i have to start on this end.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have accidentally `#import`'ed the `.m` file instead of the `.h` file.

Comment: Where do I have to check it?

Comment: Where ever you are importing your AdMob Adapter.

Comment: The adapter is a .a file

Answer (score 0):

It appears more than one class has a class variable named data.

You might want to make it a full property in your code, or change the name of your duplicate variable so it doesn't collide at compile time.

Edit: On second look, it appears you have several collisions... is there by any chance you're executing #include on the same file twice?

Perhaps #ifndef might be of use?

Comment: No, if I'm using "both" functions separately, both work... but not together.

Comment: Is there any chance you import AdMob in your controller, and also import an AdMob adapter, which happens to also import AdMob in their implementation?

Comment: If your class includes Adapter.a and also includes AdMob.h, if AdMob.h includes Adapter.a, you will get this error. Try commenting out AdMob.h and just including Adapter.a and see if it changes.